# How to run pyinstaller with Wine on Mac? I need Python 3.6 or 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, windows, macos, wine

I am using Mac OS and I need to create a windows executable for my Python script. I couldn't find anything that tells how to do it. I did install wine on Mac but not sure what to do now. Any help would be appreciated.